# Combine dataframe and check for content in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id    |    object_code    |    col_a    |    col_b
1     |    625            |    1        |    17
2     |    625            |    2        |    18
3     |    625            |    3        |    19
4     |    625            |    4        |    20
5     |    637            |    None     |    None  
6     |    637            |    None     |    None       
7     |    637            |    5        |    None       
8     |    637            |    None     |    None       
9     |    782            |    None     |    21
10    |    782            |    None     |    22
11    |    782            |    None     |    None
```

What i want to achieve is a dataframe reduced to one line per *object_code*. In addition I need a True (or something equal useful) if there's a value in at least one line inside column *col_a* (seperated for each *object_code*) - same goes for column *col_b*.
So in the end it should look like this:

```
id    |    object_code    |    col_a    |    col_b
1     |    625            |    True     |    True
5     |    637            |    True     |    False
9     |    782            |    False    |    True
```

Is this possible with a pandas function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare columns by [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) if `None` is `NoneType` or by `'None'` if strings and then aggregate [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test if at least one `True` per rows:

```
df1 = df[['col_a','col_b']].notna().groupby(df['object_code']).any().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[['col_a','col_b']].ne('None').groupby(df['object_code']).any().reset_index()
print (df1)
   object_code  col_a  col_b
0          625   True   True
1          637   True  False
2          782  False   True
```

If `id` values are important:

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['id','object_code'])
d = dict.fromkeys(cols, 'any')
d['id'] = 'first'
print (d)
{'col_a': 'any', 'col_b': 'any', 'id': 'first'}

df[cols] = df[cols].ne('None')
df = df.groupby(df['object_code']).agg(d).reset_index()
df = df[df.columns[-1:].tolist() + df.columns[:-1].tolist()]
print (df)
   id  object_code  col_a  col_b
0   1          625   True   True
1   5          637   True  False
2   9          782  False   True
```

Comment: Thank you! Took the first solution, worked perfectly!